# Strange screen ghosting issue with GNOME 3.8.4 on Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3

Since migrating to Fedora 19 and GNOME 3.8.4 I've been noticing a strange ghosting of images on my screen, where pieces of popups and parts of GUIs will sometime remain around. Running `xwininfo` doesn't report them as actually there so I'm kind of at a loss as to:

1. what is causing these
2. how to get rid of them
3. curious if anyone else has been experiencing them as well

#### Examples

Here are 2 screenshots that show these mysterious popup ghosts.

***#1***

[image: ss of ghost image #1]

***#2***

[image: ss of ghost image #2]

#### EDIT #1

*lspci -vv output*

```
$ sudo lspci -vvv -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 215a
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 41
    Region 0: Memory at f2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee0f00c  Data: 41a1
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        AFCap: TP+ FLR+
        AFCtrl: FLR-
        AFStatus: TP-
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

- **Video hardware:** Appears to be Intel card, not sure of specific model, I have a ThinkPad T410, Type #: 2516-CTO.
- **Driver:** Appears to be using the i915 Kernel module as a driver.

Comment: What video card and driver?

Comment: Also, I hate do this, but... tried Fedora 20 and Gnome 3.10?

Comment: @mattdm - No, I can though, I'll put that as option B if nothing else pans out 8-)

Comment: @mattdm - see updates, included hardware/driver info.