# How to remove "dead window parts" after GUI errors?

Tags: xorg, x11, chrome

I have experienced this problem with Chrome only (but for quite a while now, different versions) but the question is not about Chrome but about X (I guess). Sometimes (I am not aware of any pattern) an activity causes a part of the Chrome window to be redrawn (e.g. opening the context menu or the bookmark window) but this drawing (sometimes finished, sometimes an early stage, just a white or grey background) is dead then: Clicking it leads to no recognizable result.

If I move the main window then this dead part stays where it appeared (like with `position:fixed` in CSS). Thus I (with nearly no X11 background knowledge) assume it must me an additional window which somehow got lost.

Chrome works normally afterwards (but the probability for this to happen again has increased a lot); the problem is: This dead window is the "top layer" on the display i.e. it covers **everything**.

I can kill this dead window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> but that (takes some time and) kills not only the dead window but the main window, too.

**question**

Is there a way to kill **only** the dead window? Maybe some kind of window handle which can be closed externally? I would not be surprised if there is none but I'll give it a try.

**log files**

Nothing in `~/.xsession-errors` but interesting lines in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (which has an mtime which could be the moment of this event):

```
(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x3d) [0x585aad]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xorg (mieqEnqueue+0x22b) [0x5679db]
(EE) 2: /usr/bin/Xorg (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x4534a2]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7fb8059fa000+0x5b0d) [0x7fb8059ffb0d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x797b8) [0x4797b8]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0xa1e30) [0x4a1e30]
(EE) 6: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fb811996000+0xf9f0) [0x7fb8119a59f0]
(EE) 7: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x189c70) [0x589c70]
(EE) 8: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fb811996000+0xf9f0) [0x7fb8119a59f0]
(EE) 9: /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x7fb8107e8000+0x7a154) [0x7fb810862154]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libexa.so (0x7fb80ba81000+0x7d98) [0x7fb80ba88d98]
(EE) 11: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x110c61) [0x510c61]
(EE) 12: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0xd7109) [0x4d7109]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/Xorg (FreePicture+0x138) [0x5048c8]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x5e962) [0x45e962]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/Xorg (FreeClientResources+0x6c) [0x45f98c]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/Xorg (CloseDownClient+0x5f) [0x43c10f]
(EE) 17: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x3c33f) [0x43c33f]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x3cc3e) [0x43cc3e]
(EE) 19: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x2c1ba) [0x42c1ba]
(EE) 20: /lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fb810809be5]
(EE) 21: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x2c501) [0x42c501]
(EE) 
(EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the stack.
(EE) [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.    [709482.747] [mi] Increasing EQ size to 1024 to prevent dropped events.
[709482.750] [mi] EQ processing has resumed after 74 dropped events.
[709482.750] [mi] EQ processing has resumed after 74 dropped events.
[709482.750] [mi] This may be caused my a misbehaving driver monopolizing the server's resources.
```

**graphics hardware and driver**

I have an AMD E-450 (i.e. GPU integrated in the processor).

In `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` there is this line:

```
[    52.009] (--) RADEON(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon HD 6300 Series Graphics" (ChipID = 0x9806)
```

Comment: Normally those things happen by a faulty xorg driver, have you seen anything relevant in `~/.xsession-errors` `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: I have the same exact problem: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108121/strange-screen-ghosting-issue-with-gnome-3-8-4-on-fedora-19

Comment: @slm But unfortunately in this case my question is not (yet) at risk of getting closed as a duplicate... 8-)  In two days when I don't need any more rep I am going to throw a bounty at this.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think this was necessarily a dup, just pointing out the similar problem and literally no resolutions. I've looked but have been dealing w/ it, the only workaround it to kill Chrome. BTW, you should get to 20K, why stop at 10K? You have very good A's that are usually very technical!

Comment: @slm I am **not** going to stop answering questions tomorrow. I guess I will care even less than now about throwing some hundred rep away. That's what I meant.

Comment: I see what you mean, not caring about rep is all. Yeah it's meaningless in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using "xkill" app. It is designed exactly for such mishaps.